# JAVA POO - Como chamar uma função de uma Classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, funções, classes

Então estou com o seguinte problema , criei uma matriz 30x60 na qual irei gerar um numero em uma posição aleatória,até ai tudo bem.
Porém quando peguei a função que gera o numero e coloquei na classe , estou tendo problemas para chamar ela.

Meu código esta assim:
*Omiti o codigo de preenchimento da matriz pra ficar menor*

```
int [][] matrix = new int[30][60];
Caminhao caminhoes = new Caminhao();
Carro carros = new Carro();
Moto motos = new Moto();



//Utilizando as funções com objetos

carros.gerarCarro();
motos.gerarMoto();
caminhoes.gerarCaminhao();


//Código para printar a matriz após cada veiculo adicionado

    for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[x].length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[x][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

E o código na Classe que está a função está assim:

```
/Método para gerar um Carro em um lugar aleatório da matriz
public void gerarCarro(){
          Random r= new Random();
          int [][] matrix = new int[30][60];
          int a =r.nextInt(29);
    int b =r.nextInt(59);
          if(matrix[a][b] == 0 && matrix[a][b] != 2 && matrix[a][b]!=1 && matrix[a][b]!=4 && matrix[a][b]!=5){
            matrix[a][b]=3;

    }

    }
}
```

O que está errado ?

Comment: Mas qual é o objetivo do que está a tentar fazer ? que o método `gerarCarro` preencha a matriz que tem no main ? É que você está a criar uma nova dentro do método `gerarCarro`.

Comment: o método gerarCarro tem que gerar o numero 3 em uma posição aleatoria da matriz que tem o valor de 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando faz `int [][] matrix = new int[30][60];` dentro do método `gerarCarro` está a criar uma nova matriz e não a usar a que já tinha no `main`:

```
public void gerarCarro(){
    Random r= new Random();
    int [][] matrix = new int[30][60]; // <-- aqui
```

Por esse motivo a alteração que faz a seguir:

```
matrix[a][b]=3;
```

Em nada afeta a matriz que já tinha no `main`. Para fazer o que pretende tem algumas alternativas. A mais direta e comum é passar essa matriz como parâmetro ao método.

Para isso, começa por alterar o método para trabalhar com a matriz recebida:

```
public void gerarCarro(int[][] matrix){
// -------------------------------^ matriz recebida aqui
    Random r= new Random();
    //int [][] matrix = new int[30][60]; //já não cria
    int a =r.nextInt(29);
    int b =r.nextInt(59);
    if(matrix[a][b] == 0){
        matrix[a][b]=3;
    }
}
```

Neste momento pode estar a pensar: E o que aconteceu ao resto das condições que tinha no `if` ???

Bom elas não faziam sentido pois se `matrix[a][b]` for `0` então garantidamente será diferente de 1, 2, 4 e 5 tornando-as redundantes.

No `main` altera a `gerarCarro` para enviar a `matrix`.

```
//Utilizando as funções com objetos

carros.gerarCarro(matrix);
```

E para ficar tudo correto, terá que aplicar o mesmo principio aos outros métodos que geram, assumindo que tinha uma lógica idêntica neles.

Teria ainda outras coisas para melhorar, como por exemplo não criar o objeto `Random` toda vez que entra no método, mas isso já são passos para o futuro.

Comment: Muito Obrigado,deu certinho aqui , Obrigado de verdade.